# Amazing Slider and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find a solution for an image slider such as Amazing Slider and how to integrate it in my e-commerce web-app which I have developed using Angular JS. I want to have features such as lightbox and a slider with thumbnails underneath, and also video integration. I know its a lot to ask but its a shame that this very strong framework lacks (to my knowledge) a proper image viewer. Has anyone tried this integration before? Are there any other solutions. After doing a google search all I found is [bootstrap UI](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4RZIIV9DCnD6mJ4ex1f?p=preview) and a [gist](http://eraoferrors.blogspot.gr/2013/08/angularjs-lightbox-directive.html) for lightbox. But these are not anywhere near of what I am asking for. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason AngularJS does not have such an inbuilt facility is that AngularJS was not meant to address such things. Its an application framework. It is not meant to be a UI framework.

Having said that, I am assuming you have the images you want to render in some sort of collection in AngularJS. So you can just write a very simple directive which will take your collection as a ng-model and render the slider for you. This allows you to reuse this component in multiple places in your app.

If you have only one place in your app that you need the slider, then just a simple ng-repeat will suffice.

Comment: I will give it a go and I will let you know ASAP. Thanks.